# SailsJS v1.0 Bearer auth (API token)

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js, passport.js, bearer-token

**First of all this is NOT a duplicate since all the documentation/answers out there are for versions prior to v1.0 and they don't seem to work.**

I'm trying to implement a simple authentication with `passport` and SailsJS v1.0.

The problem is...since i'm new to this and sailsjs (v1) seems to lack online examples, i'm pretty stuck.

The app should work like this -> User registers, validates their email and then logs in. Upon logging in the user gets back a `accessToken` which he needs to use to make requests to protected routes (via `Bearer` or something else).

The tokens should be saved in the DB so i can invalidate them when the user changes password and such.

How could i achieve something like this ? This is what i've got so far (merging older/newer examples online).

User.js (model)

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    tokens: {
      collection: 'token',
      via: 'userId'
    }
  },
  customToJSON: function () {
    return _.omit(this, ['password'])
  },
  beforeCreate: function (user, cb) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        user.password = hash;
        return cb();
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Token.js (model)

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    token: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    userId: {
      mode: 'user'
    },
    isValid: {
      type: 'bool',
    }
  },
};
```

Since i'm very new to node and especially sails i've got quite a few questions.

1. How could i create a token on user login if the token in the DB is
   invalid (or should i just use 1 token at registration/change
   password ?)
2. How do i implement the actual authentication process
   using `passport` ?
3. Should the token be a specific format (number of characters etc) for
   security reasons ?
4. Is there a better approachto what i'm trying to achieve ? (to be
   more exact i want a REST Api back-end to serve my ReactJS front-end
   with the ability to reuse the same back-end for android/ios etc).

Any tips, links, suggestions etc will be highly appreciated. Thanks and have mercy on my lack of knowledge!

EDIT: Would this approach stop me from using social media login (i want to implement that in the future too)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use JWT for authentication.

Create file called isAuthenticated.js in api/policies folder with following code.

```
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = async (req, res, proceed) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      res.serverError(err, err.message);
    }
    if (user) {
      req.user = user;
      return proceed();
    }
    if (info) {
      return res.forbidden(info);
    }
    // Otherwise, this request did not come from a logged-in user.
    return res.forbidden();
  })(req, res, proceed);
};
```

Create strategies folder in api folder with jwt.js file and following code.

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const { ExtractJwt } = require('passport-jwt');
const passport = require('passport');

const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = JWT_SECRET;
opts.issuer = JWT_ISSUER;
opts.audience = JWT_AUDIENCE;
opts.jsonWebTokenOptions = {
  expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
};

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Passport Strategy
   */
  passport: () => {
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwtPayload, done) => {
      User.findOne({ id: jwtPayload.id }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          return done(err, null);
        }
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        }
        return done({ message: 'No user account found' }, 'No user account found');
      });
    }));
  },
};
```

And in app.js `require('./api/strategies/jwt').passport();` at top of the file.

Now you can apply policies to the routes in config/policies.js.

To generate JWT, you can use the following code.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = {
  generate: (id, email) => jwt.sign({ id, email }, jwtSecret, {
    audience: jwtAudience,
    expiresIn: jwtExpiresIn,
    issuer: jwtIssuer,
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'd rather use a token stored in the DB that i can invalidate whenver i want. Using JWT won't let me invalidate the token in case...lets say user changes his password or stuff like that.

Comment: In that case, it's better to use session based authentication.

Comment: The whole idea of my sailsjs app was to have a rest api back-end and to build my front-end in React, later on adding mobile apps in React Native. Thats why i'm trying to keep my back-end as a standalone instead of MVC.